# Delete/Replace same (code)word in one go from Visual Studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Let's say if `(click)="toggle()"` is written 10 times in same file, how can I **`delete/replace`** the same piece of code in **`one go`**?

When I select above piece of code, VSCode automatically ***`highlights`*** same code but how to **`delete/replace`** it in **`one go`**?

**Is it possible to delete/replace same piece of code in one go using VS Code?**

Comment: *Find/Replace All* doesn't work for you?

Comment: Find/replace will work but I don't want to do it. I have seen in sublime or webstorm people just replace/delete in one go. Want to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @abelenky : This is not fair in SO. After getting 39k don't act like this.

Comment: If it's in the same file, Find/Replace All is the way to do it. Insisting you want something else isn't going to change that, no matter how many times you repeat it or whether you say it in **bold**, *italics*, ***bold italics***, `code formatting`, **`bold code formatting`**, or anything else.

Answer (score 40):

- 1. Select your code
- 2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (which is `editor.action.selectHighlights`)
- 3. voila, multiple cursors done - type away.

This works without involving the Find widget because although the description of the command is a misleading "Select All Occurrences of Find Match" the actual associated command is `editor.action.selectHighlights` which doesn't need to be as a result of the Find widget.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer.  I had the exact same question as the OP, and this worked perfectly.

Comment: i agree. this is what i needed

Answer (score 17):

- Select the code you want to replace
- Execute `editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch` (on Windows it's on <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> by default) until all occurences are selected **OR** execute `actions.find` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>) followed by `editor.action.selectAllMatches` (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>)
- Now you have multiple cursors active and you are able to delete/change the text in one go.

**TIP**: `editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch` uses the current settings of the find widget regarding case sensitivity and whole word matching. You can toggle these settings with `toggleFindCaseSensitive` (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>) and `toggleFindWholeWord` (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>).

As an alternative you can just use `editor.action.startFindReplaceAction` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>) followed by `editor.action.replaceAll` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>) when you defined the strings for search and replace.

Comment: I wish I could buy you a pizza.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Multiple selections (multi-cursor)#
VS Code supports multiple cursors for fast simultaneous edits. You can add secondary cursors (rendered thinner) with Alt+Click. Each cursor operates independently based on the context it sits in. A common way to add more cursors is with **⌥⌘↓** or **⌥⌘↑** that insert cursors below or above.

Note: Your graphics card driver (for example NVIDIA) might overwrite these default shortcuts.
[image: multicusor gift vscode]

**⌘D** selects the word at the cursor, or the next occurrence of the current selection.

[image]

Tip: You can also add more cursors with **⇧⌘L**, which will add a selection at each occurrence of the current selected text.

Answer (score 0):

highlight your word/code and right click and press change all occurences and press backspace

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).